# how to access the values of an array where the values are getting pushed in a loop outside the loop block

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the values from the radio buttons in my html to my js file. By doing so I want to get the values of the elements and store them in an array. This, I will later send to the backend with the help of ajax.

This is how I went on with the codes:

```js
var civilCategory = document.getElementsByClassName("civil-category");

var civilCatInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='civil-cat']");

var civilCourt = document.getElementsByClassName("civil-court");

var civilCourtInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='civil-court']");

var lawType = document.getElementsByClassName("civil-law-type");

var lawTypeInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='civil-law-type']");

const courtToggle = document.querySelector(".civil-court-ul");

const lawTypeToggle = document.querySelector(".civil-law-type-ul");

var civilCatval = [];

var civilCourtval = [];

var civillawTypeval = [];

for (i = 0; i < civilCategory.length; i++) {
  civilCategory[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    var visibility = courtToggle.getAttribute("data-courtvisilble");

    if (visibility === "false") {
      courtToggle.setAttribute("data-courtvisilble", true);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < civilCatInput.length; j++) {
      if (civilCatInput[j].checked) {
        civilCatval.push(civilCatInput[j].value);
        console.log(civilCatval);
      }
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < civilCourt.length; i++) {
  civilCourt[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    var visibility = lawTypeToggle.getAttribute("data-lawtypevisible");

    if (visibility === "false") {
      lawTypeToggle.setAttribute("data-lawtypevisible", true);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < civilCourtInput.length; j++) {
      if (civilCourtInput[j].checked) {
        civilCourtval.push(civilCourtInput[j].value);
        console.log(civilCourtval);
      }
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < lawType.length; i++) {
  lawType[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (j = 0; j < lawTypeInput.length; j++) {
      if (lawTypeInput[j].checked) {
        civillawTypeval.push(lawTypeInput[j].value);
        console.log(civillawTypeval);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**this is what I want to get that happens only when i console log it inside the loop I want the same result when I console lof the the arrays out side the loop**

```
['land acquisation']
civil.js:50 ['meghalay high court']
civil.js:61 ['specific relief']
civil.js:34 (2) ['land acquisation', 'land acquisation']
civil.js:50 (2) ['meghalay high court', 'meghalay high court']
civil.js:61 (2) ['specific relief', 'specific relief']
civil.js:34 (3) ['land acquisation', 'land acquisation', 'comercial court']
civil.js:50 (3) ['meghalay high court', 'meghalay high court', 'meghalay high court']
civil.js:61 (3) ['specific relief', 'specific relief', 'specific relief']
```

I am new to javascript so perhaps the way I am doing this is a bit lenghty. Now since these are all events hence the values inside the array are only pushed with new values when some clicks the different radio buttons.

I want to get the arrays or rather access the arrays out of the block of the loop so that i can send them in the backend with an ajax call later. How can I do it?

I am new to js so I don't know if this is the right way to do it, please suggest me what should i do to get the entire array outside the block of the loop.

Comment: which array you mean?

Comment: var civilCatval = [];

var civilCourtval = [];

var civillawTypeval = [];

these arrays which get a new value pushed when the event is triggered

Comment: as I can see , you still can access them from out side the loop

Comment: @Mohammednaji when I console.log() them outside the lopp block it shows only one value which ever the user clicked first. Where as when i console.log() inside the loop i get the array with all the latest values that the user has clicked

Comment: Can you reduce the code here to meet the guidance prescribed by our guidance on creating a [mre]? There seems to be a lot of code that is rather extraneous to the core question at hand.

Comment: @esqew I shall remove the html then

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee, yes, for sure, it will be only one value since you are trying to console.log without any action, which means you are printing the initial value of the arrays. try to add any action like a listener on key and   print the arrays when the listener fired ,I believe you will not call the backend without a button , so check the arrays when you click that button

Comment: @Mohammednaji I did not get you can you post an ans explaining this

Answer (score 1):

the reason because you are trying to print the arrays once you call your scripts which means that you will get the initial values .
try to add another listener or action.
I edited the code and I added press key listner to check your values

```
var civilCategory = document.getElementsByClassName("civil-category");

var civilCatInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='civil-cat']");

var civilCourt = document.getElementsByClassName("civil-court");

var civilCourtInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='civil-court']");

var lawType = document.getElementsByClassName("civil-law-type");

var lawTypeInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='civil-law-type']");

const courtToggle = document.querySelector(".civil-court-ul");

const lawTypeToggle = document.querySelector(".civil-law-type-ul");

var civilCatval = [];

var civilCourtval = [];

var civillawTypeval = [];

for (i = 0; i < civilCategory.length; i++) {
  civilCategory[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    var visibility = courtToggle.getAttribute("data-courtvisilble");

    if (visibility === "false") {
      courtToggle.setAttribute("data-courtvisilble", true);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < civilCatInput.length; j++) {
      if (civilCatInput[j].checked) {
        civilCatval.push(civilCatInput[j].value);
        console.log(civilCatval);
      }
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < civilCourt.length; i++) {
  civilCourt[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    var visibility = lawTypeToggle.getAttribute("data-lawtypevisible");

    if (visibility === "false") {
      lawTypeToggle.setAttribute("data-lawtypevisible", true);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < civilCourtInput.length; j++) {
      if (civilCourtInput[j].checked) {
        civilCourtval.push(civilCourtInput[j].value);
        console.log(civilCourtval);
      }
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < lawType.length; i++) {
  lawType[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (j = 0; j < lawTypeInput.length; j++) {
      if (lawTypeInput[j].checked) {
        civillawTypeval.push(lawTypeInput[j].value);
        console.log(civillawTypeval);
      }
    }
  });
}
document.addEventListener('keypress',()=>{
  console.log(civillawTypeval)
})
```

Comment: I am sorry perhaps my question is not clear. Okay everytime the radio button is clicked I am pushing a value in the array. Now how can I get this array with the updated values out side the loop block everytime. So that when I trogger a ajax call the arrays that is passed contains all the values and not only one.

Comment: your question is clear , but your action is not clear, how you will fire the ajax ?

Comment: I will add another button in hmtl later that wil call the function. For that I want the entire array that gets updated everytime with the event I want to get the complete array out of the loop first

Comment: ok, then it is normal once you click the button , you will get the arrays and it will be up to date

Comment: what I am getting is this  0: "arbitration"
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

then suppose I prees anaother radio button the value still remains this if I console log out side the loop

where as if I console log in the loop while clicking 2 diff buttons I get this (2) ['arbitration', 'land acquisation']

I want the second result to pass as it is

Comment: can you use sandbox or codepen or  repl.it  for showing that ?

Comment: please check this .
it is working fine without any problem 
https://replit.com/@mohanagy/EarnestDigitalFiles#script.js

Comment: It is producing the result that I am already getting, but in the alert catval values are being returned correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**We need not save the form data separately. If you give valid name attributes it should work.** Only this works the action attribute should be set to api
Here I have set up a json-server (Dummy server for testing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/data" method="POST">
            <label><h2>cases</h2></label><br/>
            <input name="Cases" type="radio" value="1" class="form-check-input"/>Arbitration Cases<br/>
            <input name="Cases" type="radio" value="2" class="form-check-input"/>Land Acquisation Cases<br/>
            <input name="Cases" type="radio" value="3" class="form-check-input"/>Comercial court Cases<br/>
            <input name="Cases" type="radio" value="4" class="form-check-input"/>Others<br/>
        
        <br/>
        
            <label><h2>Court</h2></label><br/>
            <input name="court" type="radio" value="1"class="form-check-input"/>Supreme Court<br/>
            <input name="court" type="radio" value="2" class="form-check-input"/>Meghalaya High Court<br/>
        

        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**You can install json-server by following the link**
`npm i json-server`
To run json-server create a file named db.json and then its contents should look like

```
{
  "data":[]
}
```

Comment: thank you for the ans but this is not what I want. What I want to do will not require a form. Thank you for your ans